# How to update records (from list) on a new field in a table (MySQL)?

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `book`
(
    `book_id` INT(200) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `available_from` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
);
```

with the following entries:

```
INSERT INTO `books` (`book_id`, `name`, `available_from`) 
VALUES (101, 'Title 1', '(last Wednesday)'),
       (102, 'Title 2', '(last Sunday)'),
       (103, 'Title 3', '(last Tuesday)');
```

I am adding a new column to that table:

```
ALTER TABLE `books` 
    ADD COLUMN `available_from_base` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
```

and then using the following procedure to process the column `available_from` in order to get rid of the parenthesis formatting.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE parse_dates(INOUT @list_avail_from_dt VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE avail_from_dt VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
    DECLARE modif_avail_from_dt VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;

    DEClARE cur_avail_from_dt
        CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT available_from FROM books;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    OPEN cur_avail_from_dt;

    get_avail_from_dt: LOOP
        FETCH cur_avail_from_dt INTO avail_from_dt;
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE get_avail_from_dt;
        END IF;

        -- remove parenthesis
        SET modif_avail_from_dt = REPLACE(REPLACE(avail_from_dt,'(',''),')','');

        -- ====================================================
        -- HERE I WANT TO INSERT EACH OF THE ELEMENTS INSIDE
        -- BOOKS TABLE INTO THE NEW FIELD CREATED ABOVE AND 
        -- AND CALLED `available_from_base`   
        -- ====================================================
        INSERT INTO `books` (`available_from_base`) VALUES (modif_avail_from_dt);

        -- for reference only
        SET list_avail_from_dt = CONCAT(modif_avail_from_dt,";",list_avail_from_dt);
    END LOOP get_avail_from_dt;
    CLOSE cur_avail_from_dt;
END;
```

This is being executed by:

```
SET @list_avail_from_dt = ""; 
CALL parse_dates(@list_avail_from_dt);
```

However when running the above the new elements don't coincide at the same book_id(s) as I was expecting something like:

```
book_id     name        available_from          available_from_base
---------+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------
101      |   Title 1  |  '(last Wednesday)'   |     last Wednesday
102      |   Title 2  |  '(last Sunday)'      |     last Sunday
103      |   Title 3  |  '(last Tuesday)'     |     last Tuesday
```

I was think to create a temporary table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp`
(
     `available_from_base` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

and then merge this table at the end of the `books` table but still need to figure out how to join these two (I thought that this could be similar as merging two DataFrames in Python).

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand at all.  Why aren't you using a simple `update`?

```
UPDATE books
    SET modif_avail_from_dt = REPLACE(REPLACE(avail_from_dt, '(', ''), ')', '');
```